# ContentControl и DataTemplate в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Могу ли я динамически менять содержимое GroupBox таким способом 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть у меня свойство Type возвращает объект типа EconomyCar, но в ContentControl в "встает" содержимое шаблона. Идея заключалась в том, чтобы Type возвращал object (в котором EconomyCar, ExpenciveCar и так далее) и в зависимости от возвращенного типа менялось содержимое GroupBox-а.
Или как иначе это организовать?

Comment: Ну вроде все правильно, добавьте ещё недостающие DataTemplate для ExpenciveCar и прочих

Comment: @АндрейNOP проблема была в DataContext. Спасибо)